# What format for Azure Adx DataConnection do i need to MQTT app?

Tags: azure, mqtt, azure-iot-hub, azure-data-explorer, mosquitto

Following this guide: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/IoTMQTTSample/tree/master/src/Windows
I send events to IoT Hub, i can monitor the events comming in to the IoT hub.

I created an Adx-table and a Data-Connection in Azure,where i can see the events are beeing "processed":

[image: Events processed]

Creating the Data Connection i followed this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-iot-hub, and choosing JSON as the format. But the data does not show up in the actual adx-table.

**What format am i actually sending using the MQTT-to-IoT-Hub-example?**

**And what format would the Data-Map have?**
I tried this where ouput of [event](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/IoTMQTTSample/tree/master/src/Windows#running-the-code) monitor is used as column names;

```
.create table TestTable ingestion json mapping 'TestMapping' '[{"column":"origin","path":"$.origin","datatype":"string"},{"column":"payload","path":"$.payload","datatype":"string"}]'
```

[image: New Picture]

Comment: [How to test Messages arriving in Azure IoTHub](https://stackoverflow.co[m/questions/35381303/how-to-test-messages-arriving-in-azure-iothub) on the IOTHub side. [.show ingestion failures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/ingestionfailures) on the ADX side

Comment: That is great: I get the following error based on this:    BadRequest_InvalidBlob: OS Error -2146233088 (FormatMessageW() returned error 15105) (os error -2146233088)

Comment: On what side? :-) If it's on ADX, please supply activity ID / root activity ID / client request ID.

Comment: On adx side. I think the problem is where i currently define it as JSON: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-iot-hub#create-a-target-table-in-azure-data-explorer  when creating the "Data Connection". So i wonder what is the output in "NewPicture" added in the Original post, is it TEXT, Avro?

Comment: It seems you didn't declare a content type in your *az iot hub monitor-events* command. I'm guessing the default is JSON.

Comment: How do i do that? :)

Comment: You don't need to. The fact that you were able to read the data successfully indicates that it was stored as JSON.